# Looking for a simple url parsing regexp

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a simple regular expression to take a block of text, parse out all the urls from it, and return them. The urls will basically be replaced with `<a href>` tags, so `http://google.com` will become `<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>`, and so on. Hence I don't think it needs to be very thorough or allow all sorts of crazy url schemes and non english characters.

This is a regex that I came up with:

```
%http[s]?://[A-z0-9/\.\-_]+%i
```

it will match all the strings starting with http:// or https:// followed by at least one of the following characters: A-z 0-9 , dot, forward slash (/), underscore, hyphen (-), case insensitive

Can any improvements be made to it?

Comment: Do a search for "URL linkification". This question gets asked a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are not validating urls, just parsing text to find urls, so go simply with `%\bhttps?://\S+%i`

If you want to check such url is inside of `<a` tag, go with:

```
%<a\s[^>]*\bhref=['"](https?://\S+)["']%i
```

To validate url use `filter_var()` function:

```
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

Comment: Its still going in a `<a href`, if i allow all characters it will open it up to XSS

Comment: @ClickUpvote - I hope you are not the one who downvote me... I have updated my answer to include `<a` tag extension

Comment: You misunderstood, if I allow all characters after http://, then someone can write: `http://"></a><script>//malicious code here</script>` and it will be changed to: `<a href="http://"></a><script>//malicious code here</script>`

Comment: Its not validating if its a correct structure of URL, but it must validate so not all characters are allowed, otherwise its left open to XSS

Comment: @ClickUpvote - String `http://www.blab-blah-blah.zero` has valid structure, but it is not a valid url

Comment: Yes that url should be okay, it doesn't have to be a valid url, just has to look like a url and not be open to XSS. I can't use filter_var  to extract an array of urls

Comment: By the way your regexp for extracting from `<a href` is also open to XSS, since someone can write: `<a onmouseover="function() { malicious code here}" href="http://google.com"` and it will be validated.. I suggest you look into XSS for the security of any sites you work on ;)